# ArcMap freezes trying to access REST dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, rest

Attempting to access this data set via REST:

http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Property/MapServer

Steps:

- Add ArcGIS Server
- Use GIS Services
- Enter the URL (above)
- Finish

ArcMap freezes (Not Responding), or the server may be added after some time.
If server is added, no Data is available.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple or few items going on with that service.  Firstly, the New South Wales government has secured that ArcGIS Server Services Directory in a way that prevents adding it as an ArcGIS Server connection.  Specifically, they are using a network appliance or web server URL rules to block any connection to `maps.six.nsw.gov.au` that isn't for the "public" folder.  In doing this, ArcGIS Desktop cannot make a connection to see content, well, it eventually will connect but it will never show any content.

What you need to do is load a layer file into ArcMap that connects directly to the service without having to make an ArcGIS Server connection:  https://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Property/MapServer?f=lyr&v=9.3 .  You can access this link from the Services Directory REST endpoint for the service.

Even using the layer file to load the service directly, the service takes an inordinate amount of time to load.  The service appears to be fairly dense in terms of data, so that is probably a factor.  I am also guessing the ArcGIS Server instance is a bit underpowered.  They are running ArcGIS Server 10.5.1, which is a retired product, but I don't think the version itself is a factor in this situation.

Comment: Fantastic sleuthing and answer.